# Flutter: How to display phone gallery on a container?

Tags: flutter, permissions, camera, gallery, live

I found a way to display live camera on a `container()`. But I want to display gallery on `Container()` in app and control like photo example.

[image]

Is it possible in flutter ?

Comment: hi, did you implement this code?
i serch for this

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it would be possible to implement this but one things I have thought of is to request External Storage Access and maybe get the directory where all photo are stored and display the from File. However, this approach may need to a lot exceptions thrown.

I normal image_picker invokes the native channel to be able show the Android Native UI and same for iOS.